# Setting Android Home on Ubuntu. Is this redundant?

Tags: android, linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

```
# Android SDK
PATH=$PATH:/home/sudhir/Documents/Android/sdk:/home/sudhir/Documents/Android/sdk/tools
export PATH

# For SDK version r_08 and higher, also add this for adb:
PATH=$PATH:/home/sudhir/Documents/Android/sdk/platform-tools
export PATH

# Android Home
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/sudhir/Documents/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

`bash` gurus,

Is this redundant? Should bottom two lines be enough?

Comment: Yes last 2 lines are sufficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

these two lines are sufficient.

```
# Android Home
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/sudhir/Documents/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```